# How do I obtain Savage Feasts?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

How do I obtain savage feasts (besides buying them in the Auction House)? The stat buff is incredible and I would like to be able to create them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get savage feast through a barn in your garrison (at least level 2). There isn't a recipe for it. The only other way you would get it besides buying them on the Auction House would be to have your barn make them via work orders.

Comment: Specifically, from work orders from elite river beasts in Nagrand.

Comment: elite riverbeasts are one option.  However if your character is currently under ilvl 650, just take out the normal riverbeats scattered through out Draenor.

Comment: The boars in spires of Arak are fine too.